# Draw text on a 3D plane sharpDX

Tags: c#, sharpdx, hololens

I searched and didn't find a way to do that.
I want to attach labels to 3D objects using sharpDX in HoloLens app.

anyone knows how?

thanks

edit:
so I decided to convert the text to image and then put it as texture on a plane made of 2 triangles mesh.
so now I tried this code:
https://gist.github.com/naveedmurtuza/6600103

but can't include the references, how do I fix that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a game using SharpDx a few years ago, here's a video of it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDRmIY6-8Z4

If I understand you correctly, you want 3D-texts just as the ones I'm using to explain the game elements? If so, you might get some ideas from this source code:

```
protected override bool draw(Camera camera, DrawingReason drawingReason, ShadowMap shadowMap)
        {
            if (drawingReason != DrawingReason.Normal)
                return true;

            camera.UpdateEffect(Effect);
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                Effect.World = Matrix.BillboardRH(item.Target.Position + item.GetOffset(item), camera.Position, -camera.Up, camera.Front);
                Effect.DiffuseColor = item.GetColor(item);
                SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, Effect.GraphicsDevice.BlendStates.NonPremultiplied, null, Effect.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilStates.DepthRead, null, Effect.Effect);
                SpriteBatch.DrawString(Font, item.Text, Vector2.Zero, Color.Black, 0, Font.MeasureString(item.Text) / 2, item.GetSize(item), 0, 0);
                SpriteBatch.End();
            }

            Effect.GraphicsDevice.SetDepthStencilState(Effect.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilStates.Default);
            Effect.GraphicsDevice.SetBlendState(Effect.GraphicsDevice.BlendStates.Opaque);

            return true;
        }
```

Full game code is open source and available here:
https://github.com/danbystrom/Larv/blob/master/src/factor10.VisionThing/FloatingText/FloatingTexts.cs#L32

Comment: is there an option to do that without the toolkit?

I'm trying to render a 3D window with text.